# High temp even when shutdown

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, temperature

Hello i just made build my first Raspberry pi4 (8Gb) build and i have run into a weird issue. When i Turn it off with (either via terminal or normal) it seems to keep sucking energy and stays warm. when i woke up today i held my hand over the case and i was very warm 40C~ my room temp is around 20C. I made sure to properly shut it down and check only letting the cable stay connected because i noticed the high temp yesterday after a shutdown and 2 hour period as well. The red LED also stays on idk if that helps. And temperatures while running are 40C-48C so basically the same.

Further information: Raspberry pi4 8gb, Latest 32bit version of raspian (installed via NOOBS), Argon One 40Case, network boot not enabled, Wlan connection,

Answer (score 3):

The only way to "stop" the Raspberry Pi from running is to remove power. If you're supplying power through the USB-C connector, just pull that out. The red LED will go out, and you'll see it cool down then. :)

A bit different on RPi than many Linux boxes. Usually `shutdown` powers down, but that's not the case with Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Thank you very much i was worrying mine was broken since i couldn't find anything on that matter on the internet and i also have Clock speed issues. :D

Comment: @ReneH.: Glad it helped. If you don't mind, please take a moment to [read this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).  You may also find [the tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) informative.